# UMD constant of finite dimensional spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, banach-spaces, martingales

For a Banach space $B$, its *one-sided Unconditional Martingale Difference (UMD) constant* $C^-_p$ (for $p \in (1,\infty)$) is the smallest value such that for all $B$-valued martingale difference sequences $(d_n)_{n=1}^N$ we have $$\bigg(\textbf{E} \Big\|\sum_n d_n\Big\|^p\bigg)^{1/p} \le ~C^-_p \bigg(\textbf{E} \Big\|\sum_n \varepsilon_n d_n\Big\|^p\bigg)^{1/p},$$ where the $\varepsilon_n$'s are independent Rademacher RVs (uniform in $\{-1,1\}$). This was introduced by [Garling](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781468467833) and has connections with stochastic integration, see [Veraar's paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2007-135-05/S0002-9939-06-08619-9/S0002-9939-06-08619-9.pdf). If the reverse inequality is also required then $C^-_p$ is just (equivalent to) the standard UMD constant.

**Question:** Is it true that for all $d$-dim spaces the one-sided constant depends only *polylogarithmically* on $d$?

One can get dependence $\sqrt{d}$ by comparing with the Euclidean space and using the (two-sided) UMD constant of the latter, but I wonder if one can do better.

This would be interesting even restricting to Paley-Walsh martingales and when $B$ is a Banach lattice.

Comment: PS: For Paley-Walsh martingales I tried to use Pisier's inequality (actually the generalization of Hytonen and Naor https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.5375) but in particular I don't see how to properly add the information that we have a martingale